# If statement help ; different color to certain criteria

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, colors, if-statement

Im a beginner, and If statements are my weakness. I have a simple program that displays files names that are located in a certain folder. However, some files might have lines that begin with LIFT. I want to catch those files that have that certain line, and display the file name in a different color (preferably red). Here is what I have so far: Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!! Thanks!

```
public partial class ShippedOrders : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            string[] array1 = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Kaplan\Replies\");
            string[] array2 = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Kaplan\Replies\", "*.REP");
            Console.WriteLine("---Files:---");
            foreach (string name in array1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(name);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("---REP Files: ---");
            foreach (string name in array2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(name);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you talking about the file name, or within the file itself.

Comment: Why are you writing to the console in ASP.Net?

Comment: within the file. and @SLaks ; yes.

Comment: @javasocute - You should not be writting to the Console within a System.Web.UI.Page class, modify your code so it makes more sense, what exactly do you not understand about if statements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Directory.GetFiles(directoryPath) will return an array of strings listing the file names (full paths) within that directory. You're going to have to actually open and read each file, using the string array returned. Read each file line by line in a loop and test if any lines begins with "LIFT".

Also the way you set up your code-behind for this webpage is funky. You're declaring a class inside the partial class of the page. Try setting up your code like this:

```
public partial class ShippedOrders : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.goFiles();
    }

    public void goFiles()
    {
        string[] array1 = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Kaplan\Replies\");
        string[] array2 = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Kaplan\Replies\", "*.REP");
        System.IO.StreamReader file = null;
        string line = "";
        bool hasLIFT = false;

        Response.Write("---Files:---<br/>");
        foreach (string name in array1)
        {
            file = new System.IO.StreamReader(@name);
            while((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if(line.StartsWith("LIFT"))
                {
                    hasLIFT = true;
                    break;
                }
             }
             if(hasLIFT)
             {
                 Response.Write("<span style=\"color:Red;\">" + name + "</span><br/>";
                 hasLIFT = false;
             }
             else
                 Response.Write(name + "<br/>";
        }
        //and can do the same for other array
    }
}
```

Comment: while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null) 
{ 
    if (line.StartsWith("LIFT")) 
        Console.ForegroundColor = Console.Color.Red;

with both shredder and miguels code. 

am I on the right path with this?

Comment: @javasocute see my update. I've changed writing to the console to write your text in the response of the page request. this should help you get the results you're looking for

Comment: @javasocute i did another update to help you set up your code properly in the code-behind your page.

Comment: Thanks for all your help Shredder, curious, why are you using response.write instead of console. I guess i need to learn all this console and nonconsole stuff.

Comment: @javasocute Well I guess it depends on the reason you're writing these file names. Are you even seeing the output from Console.WriteLine()? I think you have to setup a custom writer for the console for that. You can use `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("debug statement");` to write to the output window in VS in debugger. But `Response.Write()` shows you the output right there on the page regardless.

Comment: Console.Writeline() works just fine. The file names display as I want them to. This is a web application, but I guess im not supposed to use console. Idk. Im gonna have to look into that sort of thing.

Comment: If it works fine, and you're getting what you want, then by all means, go for it. Seems like @Miguel can help change font color there. Sorry I changed it to Response^^ Its just more commonly used in asp.net I believe

Answer (score 1):

You can change the console output color by using the `Console.ForegroundColor` property.

To know if the file contains the text you want, you need to open it and scan the file.

Then do this:

```
if (fileContainsText) Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
else Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
Console.WriteLine(name);
```

**EDIT**

I didn't notice you were trying to write to Console inside an ASP.NET server page... in that case you need to tell us what kind of app you are creating... is it a Console application, a WebApplication or a Website... it depends.

The use of `Console` is not suited for web applications.

**EDIT 2**

By the way, you may use the `Console` only in console applications. A console application is a stand-alone windows application, that is different from a web application.

If you ever want to create a console app, in the New Project window, you can find it under **Windows** category, then you can find a project type called **Console Application**.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this inside your foreach loop:
    `if(name.contains("LIFT"))
    {
        //make red.
    }`

it does though have the issue that it only checks if the string (name) contains the string LIFT, and not if the string is in the beginning of the filename. If you want to check if LIFT is in the beggining of the file name you must use some of the Trim methods.